# Как сконфигурировать PyCharm указав, что текущий проект - проект Django?

Tags: python, django, pycharm

Подключил в PyCharm 2017.2.4 django-проект через FTP. В среде данный проект отображается просто как проект на pure-python. Как сделать так, чтобы PyCharm воспринимала данный проект именно как django-проект?
Дополнение. Виртуальная среда настроена и все необходимые зависимости подтянуты. Открывая папку, которая является корнем виртуальной среды (речь идёт об ОС windows), либо открывая папку с самим проектом - нужного эффекта не даёт. В разделе настроек интерпретатора в pycharm указана именно используемая виртуальная среда. Насколько я понимаю - необходимо "обработать напильником" настройку "Run\Debug Configurations". Хотя могу ошибаться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В настройках есть нужная вкладка
**settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Django**
там и нужно активировать поддержку **django**. Можете просто в поиске в настройках набрать **"django"** и найдёте все нужные.
Вот как у меня в англоязычном интерфейсе 
[image: скриншот настроке pycharm]

Comment: Благодарю! Помогло!

Answer (score 0):

Привет =)!
Всегда, когда работают с джанго проектами, создают виртуальное окружение. В которое устанавливаются сам джанго, его зависимости ну и нужные человеку библиотеки. И вот для обработки джанго, и всех этих библиотек отвечает питоновский интерпретатор, который нужно обязательно указывать в настройках pyCharm

> https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm-edu/configuring-available-python-interpreters.html

Официальная документации расскажет много интересного =)

Comment: Если б было всё так просто. Виртуальная среда настроена и все необходимые зависимости подтянуты. Открывая папку, которая является корнем виртуальной среды (речь идёт об ОС windows), либо открывая папку с самим проектом - нужного эффекта не даёт. В разделе настроек интерпретатора в pycharm указана именно используемая виртуальная среда. Насколько я понимаю - необходимо "обработать напильником" настройку "Run\Debug Configurations". Хотя могу ошибаться.

Comment: Пожалуйста дополните вопрос =)

Comment: Дополнил. Благодарю за замечание.